# need help correcting my code for fibonacci sequence

Tags: c, recursion, fibonacci

I need to create a program that asks the user for an integer N, and then prints out the first N terms of the fibonacci sequence using a void function for fibonacci sequence.  After one instance, the program must ask the user if he wishes to continue. If user replies Y, the program must ask user for another integer N, and then prints out the first N terms of the fibonacci sequence and so on.

I have already written code for this. It works in the first instance. The problem is, if the user chooses to do it again, the result is no longer the right fibonacci sequence. Below is the code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void printFibonacci(int n){
    static int n1=0,n2=1,n3;
    if(n>0){
         n3 = n1 + n2;
         n1 = n2;
         n2 = n3;
         printf("%d ",n3);
         printFibonacci(n-1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    char choice;
    printf("Enter the number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Fibonacci Series: ");
    printf("%d %d ",0,1);
    printFibonacci(n-2);//n-2 because 2 numbers are already printed

    printf("\nDo you wish to continue?(Y/N)");
    scanf(" %c", &choice);

    while (choice=='Y')
    {
        printf("Enter the number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Fibonacci Series: ");
    printf("%d %d ",0,1);
    printFibonacci(n-2);//n-2 because 2 numbers are already printed

    printf("\nDo you wish to continue?(Y/N)");
    scanf(" %c", &choice);
    }
  return 0;
 }
```

The expected result is the Fibonacci sequence. When I run the code above, on first instance if I say N = 5, it gives the correct result:
0,1,1,2,3. 
Problem comes after I answer yes to "Do you wish to continue? (Y/N)". If I again input N = 5, I expect to get 0,1,1,2,3 but instead, I get 0,1,5,8,13.

Comment: You should reset static var n1,n2,n3 to 0 I think.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is using those static variables. They keep their values even out of scope, which means that when the function is recalled both n1 and n2 will have their last assigned values.
I solved that issue by passing n1 and n2 by parameters. These functions replace your printFibonacci.

```
void printFibonacci2(int length, int n1, int n2) {
    int n3;
    if(length > 0) {
        n3 = n1 + n2;
        n1 = n2;
        n2 = n3;
        printf("%d ", n3);
        printFibonacci2(length - 1, n1, n2);
    }
}

void printFibonacci (int n)
{
  printFibonacci2(n, 0, 1);
}
```

You can pretty up the code, but the issue is solved.

Answer (score 2):

We can preserve your function signatures by adding an `else` case to `printFibonacci()` to reset its static variables when `n == 0`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printFibonacci(int n) {
    static int n1 = 0, n2 = 1, n3;

    if (n > 0) {
        n3 = n1 + n2;
        n1 = n2;
        n2 = n3;
        printf("%d ", n3);
        printFibonacci(n - 1);
    } else {
        n1 = 0;
        n2 = 1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    char choice = 'Y';

    while (choice == 'Y')
    {
        printf("Enter the number of elements: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        printf("Fibonacci Series: ");
        printf("%d %d ", 0, 1);
        printFibonacci(n - 2); // n - 2 because 2 numbers are already printed
        printf("\n");

        printf("Do you wish to continue? (Y/N): ");
        scanf(" %c", &choice);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Not my first choice but the simplest way out of a messy problem:

```
> ./a.out
Enter the number of elements: 10
Fibonacci Series: 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 
Do you wish to continue? (Y/N): Y
Enter the number of elements: 10
Fibonacci Series: 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 
Do you wish to continue? (Y/N): N
>
```